# Remove space before div using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have the following code:

```
<div id="one">1</div> <div id="two">2</div> <div id="three">3</div>
```

Is there way for me to remove the space before div "three"? So I end up with this:

```
<div id="one">1</div> <div id="two">2</div><div id="three">3</div>
```

Comment: Are these children of another element? In what browser does that space matter?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var el = document.getElementById('three');
var space = el.previousSibling;
if (space.nodeType == 3) {
    space.parentNode.removeChild(space);
}
```